# How to calcute a determinant of this matrix?

Tags: matrices, induction, determinant

\begin{vmatrix}
-t &  1 &  0 & 0& \ldots & 0 &  0 &0\\
 n & -t &  2 & 0& \ldots & 0 &  0 &0\\
 0 & n-1& -t & 3&\ldots & 0 &  0 &0\\
 0 &  0 & n-2& -t& \ldots & 0& 0  &0\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots& \ddots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots\\
 0 &  0 &  0 & 0&\ldots & -t& n-1&  0 \\
 0 &  0 &  0 & 0&\ldots & 2& -t &  n \\
 0 &  0 &  0 & 0&\ldots &  0&1 & -t
\end{vmatrix}

It is needed to find an eigenvalue. I just know that for $n=m$ there are Fibonacci number $F_{m+2}$ summands in the determinant formula.

Comment: You appear to have a [tridiagonal matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tridiagonal_matrix). One thing you can do is see the determinant section of that page for a recursive formula for the determinant.

Comment: @Andrey Komisarov I don't understand your Fibonacci number comment.

Comment: @Max for n=1 there are t^2-1 (2 addend), for n=2 there are (3 addend), for n=3 there are (5 addend)...

Comment: I think you mean "summand". Edit: Google says "addend" is valid (though I still think "summand" is more common).

Comment: @Max Sorry, I mixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your matrix is $-tId$ plus the matrix that appears in Proposition 2 on page 16 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/1210.8062.pdf

The eigenvalues are thus $n-t, n-2-t, \ldots, 2-n-t, -n-t$.

Same solution in more concrete language: Consider the operator $w\frac{\partial}{\partial z}+z\frac{\partial}{\partial w}$ acting on the space of homogeneous degree $n$ polynomials in $z$ and $w$. A natural basis for that space is $z^n, z^{n-1}w, \ldots, w^n$; in that basis the matrix of this operator is like the one in the problem with $t=0$. However, in the basis $(z+w)^{n-k} (z-w)^{k}$ the matrix is diagonal with eigenvalues $n-2k$.